# Virtual Desktops

Tags: vmware-workstation

We are planning on testing virtual desktops and would like to run them side by side with the physical workstations until users and the bosses are comfortable. The problem is that i don't have enough IP address on my current subnet. Is there a way around this ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean virtual machines, not [virtual desktops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop). The IP Problem can easily be solved by using NAT in the host machine, by doing that the VM accesses the Network through the Host, while the Host provides router functionality. This Setup is the default for VMWare, as well as Virtualbox afaik, so no need for additional IPs.